# background-color:でサイト（https://support.google.com/*）が正しく表示されない場合の対処方法

Tags: css

stylusで
*{

background-color:#006400 !important; 

}

と記述した場合にサイト（https://support.google.com/*）が正しく表示されないのですがcssを特定のurlに適用しないなどの対処方法を教えてください。

Comment: 先読みについて教えてください。参考urlなど教えてください。(?!https\:\/\/support\.google\.com.*).*と記述した場合にどうなりますか。またどのように記述しますか。

Comment: chrome拡張機能のstylusを使用しています。

Answer (score 1):

Stylusでは適用先URLを正規表現で指定できます。「適用先:正規表現に一致するURL」にしてください。
たとえば、先読みを使って`(?!https\:\/\/support\.google\.com.*).*`とかはどうでしょうか。